# Glow or Sun light effect in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I need Glow or Sun light effect on my UIViewController(Some thing like this : http://www.thewhitegoddess.co.uk/the_elements/the_planets/images/sun.jpg).

I try this https://github.com/thesecretlab/UIView-Glow (http://www.secretlab.com.au/blog/2012/06/23/glowing) and drop shadow effect on layer but both when I increase the size of effect it not working.

please guide me and provide solution.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of glow that you could use, you need to mix a bit with the colors and the glow, but it´s a start for you. I have also included a animation example if you need it:

**With animation:**

```
func makeViewShine(view: UIView) {
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    view.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .curveEaseInOut, .repeat, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {() -> Void in
        view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
        }, completion: {(finished: Bool) -> Void in
            view.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}
```

**Without animation:**

```
func makeViewShine(view: UIView) {
    view.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    view.layer.shadowOffset = .zero
}
```

To use it, simply call the method and pass the view.

Comment: #Rashwan L, I want view.layer.shadowRadius = 100.0 or 200.0 or 300.0 for full screen with animation. when I change shadowRadius 10 to 100 it is not working :(
But, thank u